# Changing webcam brightness from another form by using trackbar in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I am trying to change the webcam brightness in Form2 by using trackbar in the Form3. I can't send the value of it or i can't use it in Form2. Since i am planning to design a UI, I need to achieve this that way. Can you help me to achieve this?

This is my code of Form2 below.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;


namespace MUI
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

       
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;

        

        #region Webcam Frames
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += videoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += f3.videoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.Start();
           
            f3.Show();
        }
        #endregion

        

        #region Bitmap Creating
        public void videoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        }
        #endregion
      

        #region Device List
        public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               
            filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filterInfoCollection)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice();

        }
        #endregion

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoCaptureDevice.IsRunning == true)
            {
                videoCaptureDevice.Stop();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code of Form3 below.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

namespace MUI
{
    
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();

            label6.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
            if (f2.pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {


                BrightnessCorrection brightness = new BrightnessCorrection(trackBar1.Value);
                f2.pictureBox1.Image = brightness.Apply((Bitmap)f2.pictureBox1.Image.Clone());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: Remove this: `Form2 f2 = new Form2();` to begin with. Instead of setting the `Image` Property of a Control, in an event handler that handles events NOT raised in the UI Thread, use a class object that exposes a Bitmap object. Set this object to the new Frame and set the `PictureBox.Image` property to this Bitmap. When the Frame changes, set the Bitmap object with the new value and `Invalidate()` your PictureBox. Use you routine to change the brightness of the same Bitmap object. Some locking required, probably.